# How to calculate successive MD5 hashes?

Tags: c#, md5

An application receives chunk of bytes. After each chunk, the app needs to calculate the MD5 of all the data received so far.

It seems like the built-in MD5 class is not useable in this situation because calling TransformFinalBlock() is, well, final. I need to get the MD5 hash so far and yet keep using the MD5 instance to give it the next chunk.

```cs
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
while(true)
    {
    byte[] chunk = GetNextChunk();
    if (chunk == null)
        break;
    md5.TransformBlock(chunk, 0, chunk.Length, null, 0);  // fails here on second loop
    md5.TransformFinalBlock(chunk, 0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("hash = {0}", md5.Hash);
    }
```

I have to call TransformFinalBlock before I can access the Hash property. But once I do, I can't call TransformBlock again.

The code above prints the hash of the first chunk just fine.
The second hash it needs to print is the hash of the first and second chunk concatenated together.
The third hash would for all three chunks concatenated.
Etc...

Is there a C# implementation of MD5 out there that lets me continue feeding it data even after I've obtained a hash?

Comment: You commented `// fails here on second loop`, why did it fail?

Comment: Ignore my suggestion (which i already deleted). The byte array that is the basis for the value which `md5.Hash` returns will only be computed within the TransformFinalBlock method. Bummer...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? As this may be an X Y problem.

Comment: The problem you're having is that `TransformFinalBlock` can only be called once the whole stream is retrieved and the final chunk is to be calculated, however in your case it appears you don't know the length of the total stream thus you can never know when to call the final block calculation.

Comment: I eventually found a different solution. But back then, the intent was to produce:
hash(chunk1), 
hash(chunk1 + chunk2), 
hash(chunk1 + chunk2 + chunk3), 
etc...